# ¿Como crear un histograma con anchuras distinctas por intervalo?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Como podría generar histogramas con distinto ancho de intervalo (clase), considerando que tengo los datos del intervalo y su respectiva frecuencia.

```py
    inf = [0,1,2,3,4,5,10,15,20,25,30] #limite inferior

    sup = [1,2,3,4,5,10,15,20,25,30,50] #limite superior

    frec = [18,165,112,87,43,117,51,32,10,8,8] # frecuencia
```

Comment: Has intentado algo?

Comment: Mayúsculas == Gritar. Edita el título por favor, gracias :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`plt.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) acepta unos parámetros útiles en este caso:

- `x`: las posiciones en el eje `x`
- `height`: las alturas de cada barra
- `width`: la anchura de cada barra (o una anchura para cada una por separado, o una anchura igual para todas)
- `align`: `center` (por defecto, centrado en las posiciones de `x`) o `edge` (las barras empiezan en las posiciones de `x`)

Para las anchuras, hay que calcular las diferencias entre `sup` e `inf`. Lo más fácil va con numpy, que lo hace en una sola operación.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

inf = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30]  # limite inferior
sup = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 50]  # limite superior
frec = [18, 165, 112, 87, 43, 117, 51, 32, 10, 8, 8]  # frecuencia

inf = np.array(inf)
sup = np.array(sup)
frec = np.array(frec)
plt.bar (inf, frec, width=sup-inf, align='edge', ec='white')

plt.xticks(np.concatenate((inf, sup)))
plt.show()
```

[image: ejemplo de la histograma]

PD: Para obtener una histograma con la densidad (cada barra con una superficie relativa a su participación al total, y todas sumando a uno), se puede hacer calculando `frec/(sup-inf)/frec.sum()`.

También se puede aproximar un [kde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) tomando una muestra artificial:

```py
suma = frec.sum()
plt.bar(inf, frec/(sup-inf)/suma, width=sup-inf, align='edge', ec='white')

muestra = np.concatenate([np.linspace(i, s, f) for i, s, f in zip(inf, sup, frec)])

from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
kde = gaussian_kde(muestra)
x = np.linspace(inf[0], sup[-1], 500)
plt.plot(x, kde(x), color='crimson')
plt.xticks(np.concatenate((inf, sup)))
plt.show()
```

[image: densidad y kde]

Comment: AMIGO, DE VERDAD MUCHAS GRACIAS, ME SALVASTE; ESTABA BASTANTES HORAS CON ESTE DETALLE. ES EXACTAMENTE LA RESPUESTA QUE BUSCABA; MI PROBLEMA FUE EN EL ANCHO QUE MANTENÍA CONSTANTE, LO SOLUCIONASTE CON UN ***width = sup - inf***. ESTOS SON LOS RESULTADOS QUE PUDE OBTENER. GRACIAS POR TU APORTE, POR TU TIEMPO. [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxoMB.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxoMB.png) [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBkUl.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBkUl.png)